# Admob's NativeExpressAdView not showing in Custom view Android

Tags: android, admob, customdialog

[image]

I want NativeExpressAdView on Exit dialog. Exit dialog is custom dialog created in app. code for custom dialog are below.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.out.println("IN ON BACK PRESSED:");
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SplashActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.exit_dialog);

    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exit_dialog, null);
    dialog.setContentView(main);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)main.findViewById(R.id.layoutAdd);

    NativeExpressAdView mNativeExpressAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
    mNativeExpressAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, AdSize.AUTO_HEIGHT));
    mNativeExpressAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8410399846074282/9976822052");
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

    linear.addView(mNativeExpressAdView);
    mNativeExpressAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

    dialog.setTitle("Title...");

    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
    text.setText("Are you sure you wants to exit ?? " + R.string.app_name);


    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button btnRateus = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnRateus);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    btnRateus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
            // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            }
        }
    });

    Button btnConfirm = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Its not working directly so i was try to inflate NativeExpressAdview in Linearlayout but it not displayed in linearlayout too. Please help me on that ... Thank you in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the AUTO_HEIGHT attribute as mentionned in the official native ad express documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native-express) :

> At this time, the AUTO_HEIGHT constant and FLUID ad size should not be used with Native Ads Express.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with this

```
        // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) main.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
```

On your Code

```
    NativeExpressAdView mNativeExpressAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
    mNativeExpressAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(AdSize.FULL_WIDTH, AdSize.AUTO_HEIGHT));
    mNativeExpressAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-8410399846074282/9976822052");
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

    linear.addView(mNativeExpressAdView);
    mNativeExpressAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Are You Sure to Exit?"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_text"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Rate Us!"
                android:id="@+id/btnRateus"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                style="@style/btnNew" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                style="@style/btnNew" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Exit"
                android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                style="@style/btnNew" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relAds"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2177258514"
            ads:adSize="280x250">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```